# How do you prevent a checkerboard getting our of view when changing the resolution?

Tags: javascript, center

So I'm currently working on a project that requires a grid/checkerboard. I've already made my grid in Javascript and I've also managed to center my grid.

The problem I'm having is that when I change my resolution with the device toolbar, the grid gets out of view. My goal is to make the whole grid visible no matter what phone or computer I use.

I would appreciate the help from you guys!

**This is how I'm making my grid.**

```
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    grid[i] = new Array(col);
}

//making a spot for every grid.
for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = new Spot(i, j);
    }
}
```

**This is how I'm drawing the grid.**

```
    function Spot(i, j) {
this.x = i;
this.y = j;

this.show = function (color) {
    fill(color);
    rect(this.x * w, this.y * h, w - 1, h - 1);

}
```

}

w is the width of ONE single grid and h is the height of ONE single grid. col and row are the amount of rows and columns I want the grid to have.

I also call the function "this.show" every frame. The result looks like this:
[The grid that is out of view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLbRG.png)

Comment: Please do some research about responsive UI. You don't mention any technology you using and don't show any code, so it's hard to propose any helpful answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow `@gabbe 1237`.
We need more information to help you. please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add your code & attempt.

Comment: What does `rect` do? Are you using some library? Is this on a web page / HTML? Drawing on a `canvas`? It is not clear what kind of output technology and elements you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check against the media type:

```
var l_strMobileMedia = '(max-width:320px)'
        var mqList = window.matchMedia(l_strMobileMedia);
        if(!mqList.matches){
            l_strMobileMedia = '(max-width:481px)'
            mqList = window.matchMedia(l_strMobileMedia);
        }   

        if(!mqList.matches){
            l_strMobileMedia = '(max-width:768px)'
            mqList = window.matchMedia(l_strMobileMedia);
        }   

        if(s_bIsMobile == null || s_bIsMobile != mqList.matches){
            Session.set_mobile_layout(mqList.matches);
        }
        s_bIsMobile = mqList.matches;
        return mqList.matches;
```

I hope this gets you started. If you want to do it in realtime, you need to hook to window resize event or set a timer that does the queries for you.